# Can you access the Roma Street Parklands from Roma Street Station, without a train ticket?

Tags: train-stations, brisbane, parks-and-gardens

The [Roma Street Parklands in Brisbane](http://www.romastreetparkland.com/pages/default.aspx3) are located just on the north edge of the city centre, and feature a nice variety of plants, landscaped gardens, grass etc. They also have some rather unusual locals living there...

[image: One of the locals]

From much of the city centre, the obvious way to get to them would be via Roma Street station. The [parklands website describes](http://www.romastreetparkland.com/explore/Pages/gettingthere.aspx) how to enter the park from the station tunnel and platform 10. The only trouble is, coming from town, there are barriers at each ends of the station tunnel that you'd need to pass through.

If you're coming in by train, that's no a problem, since you can just exit on the platform 10 side and go into the gardens. However, from town on foot, that isn't the case.

Is it possible for a pedestrian to enter the gardens from the station for free, or would you have to buy a ticket to get through (or more likely just take a long walk to another park entrance!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, but not all that widely advertised!

When you get to the station, head to one of the ticket gates with a member of staff on it. Ask them if you can go through the underpass to get to the gardens, and [they'll give you a visitor pass](https://foursquare.com/item/4c9c297146978cfa6fe88b7f) and let you through. When you get to the gateline at the other side, again head for a staff member, and give them your pass. They'll open the gate and let you out. From there, follow the signs up up up and into the parklands!

[image: The best photo I could manage of the visitor ticket]

Alternately, if you have a Go Card, you can touch in to open one set of gates, then touch out at the other side of the station and you won't be charged.